# Agora SDK not working in Windows Build. VideoSurface.cs always gets tmpi = -1 in Update

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, agora.io

I am trying to implement Screen broadcast with Unity using the `Agora Video Chat SDK for Unity`. I used [this](https://gist.github.com/jakep84/f2c124249fa294aa75544f08faa43c5c) source, which doesn't work initially. But after modifying the code as below, I am able to receive my own stream through the server,  inside Unity editor (2019.1.2f1).

```
    //Adding inside Start
       mRtcEngine.OnJoinChannelSuccess = Joined;
    }

    private void Joined(string channelName, uint uid, int elapsed)
    {
        var videoSource = FindObjectOfType<VideoSurface>();
        videoSource.SetForUser(uid);
        videoSource.SetEnable(true);
    }
```

But nothing happens in the Windows build. I checked the `VideoSurface.cs` file. I am continuously getting `tmpi = -1` inside `Update`. What could be the reason?

PS. I check all firewall permissions for the build. Also, the user is able to join the channel. It's just the stream that is not being received. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to modify the code like that. And also, in the code above you register the callback for the local user.  If you want to show remote user's video, you should register the callback for OnUserJoined().

Have you seen the tutorial about the Screensharing? https://www.agora.io/en/blog/how-to-broadcast-your-screen-with-unity3d-and-agora/

Please try that.  If you are still confused, you may take a look at [this github repo.](https://github.com/icywind/ARUnityClient)  It has different contents to share, but the concept and Agora API usage are pretty much the same.

Comment: I have done this inside `OnUserJoined`  to receive my own stream through the server, for testing. Without doing this, the video surface won't display anything inside Unity editor either. Yes, I followed the same tutorial. Is it not possible to receive my own stream through the server? How am I receiving this inside Unity editor?